# ARKit attach ARAnchor to barcode which is movable

Tags: swift, arkit

Hello I'm very new in developing with `ARKit` so it might be a basic question but can I attach a `ARAnchor` to a moving object like an out printed barcode?

I'm trying to develop a app where different objects should be displayed on top of different barcodes but the barcodes should be movable and the objects should follow them.

Is this possible with `ARKit` and the `CIDetector` class or any other barcode scanner library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. *ARKit* does not allow marker tracking in any form (yet?).

You could either look into other AR-Frameworks or track the position of barcodes using the [*Vision*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision)-Framwork wich can detect qr- and barcodes.
Then you place an `ARAnchor` on the position you detected with the *Vision*-Framework.